# Check if a sentence is a pangram (sentence that contain all letter s in the alphabet)

Tags: c

I need to get 10 words and check if they are a pangram (sentence that contain all letters in the alphabet)
or stop getting words if my program already find a pangram even if the user doesn't put 10 words and my program stops getting words after the first word. Someone knows why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_NAMES 10
#define LONG 50

int main()
{
    char names[MAX_NAMES][LONG] = {0};
    bool flage = true;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char allAlphabet[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    int countAlfa = 0;
    
    printf("Enter up to 10 words, try to make a pangram:\n");
    for(i = 0; (i < MAX_NAMES) && (flage == true); i++)
    {
        fgets(names[i], LONG, stdin);
        names[i][strcspn(names[i], "\n")] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(allAlphabet); j++)
        {
            if(names[i][k] = allAlphabet[j])
            {   
                countAlfa++;
                k++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        if(countAlfa == 26)
        {
            printf("It's a pangram?\n");
            printf("Yes!\n");
            flage = false;
        }
    }
    if(countAlfa != 26)
    {
        printf("It's a pangram?\n");
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(names[i][k] = allAlphabet[j])` Seems like you'd want `==` there. `allAlphabet` is not a 0 terminated string so using strlen on it won't work.

Comment: You don't ever reset k to 0 or break your loop when k goes past the end of the string being checked. `countAlfa` is increased anytime a letter is found, not just a unique letter so entering "abcde" twice makes `countAlfa` 10, not 5 as it should be. You might want to move the check for `countAlfa == 26` inside the loop right after you increment `countAlfa` otherwise you can easily go past it and since the check is `==` instead of `>=` it fais.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues

1. You had some bugs in your code. For example, `if(names[i][k] = allAlphabet[j])` is doing assignment, not an equivalency check. You meant to use `==`. This was causing things to get messsed up.
2. Second, I did run you code and it worked if I typed out "abc....wxyz". However, if I did it backwards like "zyxw...cba" it wouldn't work.

Here's a program I wrote that is what you're looking for. Please note, I do not check for overflow of the character arrays. I'm just trying to give you a working example and I made the capacities of the arrays large enough for it to work without checking.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_NAMES 10
#define LONG 100

int main()
{
    char names[MAX_NAMES][LONG] = { 0 };
    bool flage = true;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char allAlphabet[] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
    unsigned allAlphabetLength = sizeof(allAlphabet) / sizeof(allAlphabet[0]);
    int countAlfa = 0;

    char buf[27];   // stores all the unique alphabetic characters found so far
                    // at a given point while searching through a string
    buf[0] = '\0';
    unsigned bufIndex = 0;

    char result[1000];
    result[0] = '\0';
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++) {
        fgets(names[i], LONG, stdin);   // get the current string
        names[i][strcspn(names[i], "\n")] = 0;  // get rid of newline character
        strcat(result, names[i]);   // append current string to result array
        unsigned len = strlen(result); // get the length of the result array
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < len; j++ ) {   // go through every character in the result array
                                                // add it to buf if it's alphabetic and hasn't 
                                                // been encountered before
            char ch = result[j];  // get the character
            if (!isalpha(ch))   // not alphabetical character. Just continue to next character
                continue;
            unsigned bufLen = strlen(buf);  // search through buf to see if the current alphabetic
                                            // character already exists in buf. If it doesn't, add
                                            // it to buf since we've now encountered a new alphabetic
                                            // character not seen before
            bool found = false;
            for (unsigned k = 0; k < bufLen; k++) {
                if (buf[k] == ch) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                buf[bufIndex++] = ch;
                buf[bufIndex] = '\0';
            }
        }

        if (strlen(buf) == 26) {    // at the end, if buf is size 26 that means it encountered all 26 letters
                                    // of the alphabet
            printf("%s is a pangram\n", result);
            break;
        }
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output

```
abcde blah blah blah
this is a sentence
fghijkl
this is another sentence
lmnopqrstuvwx
blah
yz
abcde blah blah blahthis is a sentencefghijklthis is another sentencelmnopqrstuvwxblahyz is a pangram
```

Comment: `if (len < 26)` doesn't seem right. The code expects the words to be entered one per line so this will reject everything. `===` in your description of one of the issues looks like a typo for `==`.

Comment: Thanks in regards to the ```===``` I just accidentally put in another ```=```. I just realized I misunderstood the original problem. I thought he was supposed to check if each line is a pangram. I will fix delete my post and fix it.